# error :not a statement

Tags: java, notepad++

So i started in September my university and i have a class that is introduction to programming and i have to do a program that recognize 3 numbers and tell how many are equal for example: 30 30 2 "2 numbers are equal" but i get error :not a statement  on "else **(** n1!=n2 && n2!=n3 && n3!=n1 ); {

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Equal {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );

        int n1, n2, n3;
        int a = 3;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 0;

        System.out.println("choose tree numbers:");

        n1 = in.nextInt();
        n2 = in.nextInt();
        n3 = in.nextInt();

        if ((n1==n2 && n1==n3 || n2==n1 && n2==n3 || n3==n1 && n3==n2)) {
        //Then the tree numbers are equal;
        System.out.println( "There are: " + a + " equal numbers" );
        }

        if ((n1!=n3 && n1==n2 || n2!=n1 && n2==n3 || n3!=n2 && n3==n1 )) {
        //Then only two numbers ill be the same;
        System.out.println( "There are: " + b + " equal numbers" );
            }   
        else ((n1!=n2 && n2!=n3 && n3!=n1)); {
        //All the numbers are not equal;
        System.out.println( "There are: " + c + " equal numbers" );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i remove i get 2 error's saying that i need the ";" and the same error i said in question ...

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 else ( n1!=n2 && n2!=n3 && n3!=n1 ); {
```

to

```
 else if ( n1!=n2 && n2!=n3 && n3!=n1 ) {
```

Comment: if i do that ill get 2 errors on line 25 saying "bad operands types for binary operato "&&" and "||"

Comment: You need to use more parenthesis to make your if-statement more clear to the compiler. For instance, if ( (n1!=n3 && n1==n2) || (n2!=n1 && n2=n3) || (n3!=n2 && n3==n1) )

Comment: also you have a single = inside one of your if-statements. (n2!=n1 && n2=n3) should be (n2!=n1 && n2==n3)

Comment: i still get my first error ill edit the code and put the new one

Comment: i found the answer i just had to put "else if { and it worked thx for pushing me up in the right way

Answer (score 0):

```
if (condition1) { do_something; }
else if (condition2) { do_something_else; }
else { do_a_different_thing; }
```

A bare else-clause, by definition, does not take a condition - it fires if the preceding if/else-if clauses *don't* fire. I guess you could think of it as an *implicit* condition: `if (!condition && !condition2)`.
(But note that, *in general*, you are not required to follow the if/else-if/else pattern. You could have multiple ifs in a row with no else-ifs or else-clause, or you could have an if/else with no else-ifs, etc. It all depends on the exact logic of the situation.)

A couple of suggestions.
It's really good that you're thinking about all of the possible cases. But here, you have three numbers, and if you've already determined that it is NOT the case that all three of them match, and it is NOT the case that two of them match, then the only possibility left is that none of them do. So you don't have to test for that case explicitly.
Similarly, in your first condition, checking for a three-way match, you don't have to explicitly test every combination either. If n1==n2 && n1==n3, then by transitivity n2==n3 and all three match. The order doesn't matter.

Have fun!